# How to pretty print or format stack trace from python?

Tags: python, exception, formatting

I receive python stack traces from logs and they sometimes come in very weird format, e.g. no new lines or incorrectly formated. Here is an syntactic example:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> File "<stdin>", line 2, in bar File "<stdin>", line 2, in foo ValueError
```

Unfortunately, there is no way I can change the format of the logs, as I don't have an access to that system.

Is there an automatic way of formatting those exceptions to standard python format, so that it would look something like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in bar
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in foo
ValueError
```

I've quickly went through [traceback](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) module's documentation, but it seems it's only for runtime exceptions.

Comment: Uh, with simple regex it seems to work: `(File((?!File)[\s\S])*)` substitution: `\n  \1`. Not perfect, but better that original. Probably someone could suggest better alternatives.

Comment: Are they always weirdly formatted when present in those logs? If so it is likely a piece of software between Python and those logs is flattening the output by replacing newlines with spaces. Something like the regex suggested by @grundic should do the trick. Depending on how robust you need the solution it may be sufficient to just insert a newline before every occurrence of " File ".

Comment: Ha, ha! The regex suggested by @grundic was actually the topic starter :)
I wrote in the original question, that I don't have access to the log system and can't influence it.